# Property exists but throws undefined

Tags: react-native

In the following example, I'm setting a simple array object to state and assigning it to deck-swiper. If I stringify object in renderitem it displays the right text. What (surprisingly) isn't working is that if I try to access property (a or b in this example), it throws undefined error.

```
export class RevisionScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let myData = [
      {a: 1, b: 'as'},
      {a: 2, b: 'sd'},
    ]; 
    (() => {
      this.setState({data: myData});
    })();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 50, flex: 1}} clickable={true}>
        <Swiper
          cards={this.state.data}
          renderCard={(card, index) => {
            return (
              <View style={{height: 400, width: 150}}>
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(card)}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Above code prints

{"a":1,"b":"as"}

But, if I make it `<Text>{card.a}</Text>` it throws can't undefined error.
Interestingly, if I do `<Text>{card}</Text>` it throws error of keys {a,b} found.

Note: I found that if I set state to these values in the constructor itself, it works fine. But, I don't want to set values in constructor.

Comment: why you creating closure for setting state ? will it execute r u sure ? just use this 
      this.setState({data: myData})

Comment: If I do that directly, it will warn about using setState in componentDidMount(). I can confirm it runs.

Comment: it gives you warning because react has changed life cycle methods ...